# Custom web api returns dynamic links for rich text field if logged in to sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor, webapi

I have created a custom web api which converts glass object to json string. The glass object involves rich text field where internal links can be used. The link is fully rendered to absolute path in the response if not logged-in to sitecore but if logged-in to sitecore the dynamic sitecore link from the rich text html is returned. 
I know this is the expected behavior in sitecore but I'm wondering if there is any way force the field to pass through the rendering pipeline always.

I create glass sitecore context in api controller to access the item

```
new SitecoreContext(Context.Database)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the current request to be served in Normal mode by setting the display mode in your code:

```cs
Sitecore.Context.Site.SetDisplayMode(Sitecore.Sites.DisplayMode.Normal, Sitecore.Sites.DisplayModeDuration.ResetAfterRequest);
```

Glass uses the `Sitecore.Context.PageMode` internally, forcing the mode to normal will cause Glass to use it's own internal data mappers rather than using Sitecore's `Renderfield` pipelines.

Comment: Thanks @jammykam it worked. I believe this only sets the display mode for the current request and resets it back.

Comment: Yes, the second parameter is sets the `DisplayModeDuration`. Valid values are **Remember**, **Temporary** or **ResetAfterRequest**. I believe it resets it back but please try Temporary if you have issues.

Comment: I had issues with experience editor and preview when i used `ResetAfterRequest`, I had to set the Display mode back to the original state once my glass elements are formed. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting it to Temporary? That should mean the display mode cookie is not changed.